# Orientation of the Dark Matter Halo in Andromeda Galaxy

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, dark-matter

In this paper: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/789/1/62#apj496316t3

Refer to the Discussion and Concluding Remarks section. It says,
"This result also indicates that the major axis of the M31 dark halo is perpendicular to its disk and nearly aligned with the planar distribution of a subgroup of its satellites."

Is this an isolated paper that states this, or is it an established fact that the major axis of the dark matter halo is perpendicular to the galactic plane of Andromeda?

What about other galaxies, like the Milky Way? Is this also observed in other galaxies?

Comment: have you done any part of the literature research you suggest? What are the results of that?

Comment: The major axis being perpendicular to the galactic plane looks a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: @Angela yes, that you write. I mean: where did you search for literature? What were the search terms you used? So that we can understand what part of the literature research you ask you conducted already yourself. No point that we repeat what you ask and already did.